# Is the workspace in eclipse completely private from others to reach and view?

Tags: eclipse, security, cloud, workspace, privacy

This might sound like a stupid question to ask, but I'm curious if **it is possible for others to view and reach different user's eclipse projects?**

I know there is GitHub, but I have not leashed my workspace to a central source or cloud such as Git. Just a question regarding *privacy* and *security*.

Let's say you are coding a program in Java with eclipse and it might contain some sensitive information. **Is the project completely safe on your computer? Or are there any settings you need to change in order for it to be secure? Like setting a password on the workspace or so?**

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: It is just a set of folders on your machine like any other folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Eclipse is started, it asks you for a workspace location. Anyone who has access to that location would be able to view your workspace.

To view your current workspace location go to: File -> Switch Workspace -> Other...

Comment: I see, I wonder more if you would be able in someway to access my workspace? Like if eclipse is uploading projects for everyone to view.

Comment: No, not unless you've done something like put your workspace on a publicly shared drive/folder. It will be just as secure as any other file/folder in the same root location.